# Why 'go vet' failing with go build.... signal: killed error?

Tags: go, glide-golang, golangci-lint

We are using The Kubernetes executor for GitLab Runner, as part of GitLab CI
Go vet is failing with error--go build github.com/hashicorp/cdktf-provider-aws-go/aws/v9/wafv2: /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile: signal: killed

I tried increasing the GitLab runner memory to 16GB and tried. Then also failed.

I am not able to replicate the failure locally, so I cannot find the exact reason for the failure.

is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

after upgrading cdktf-provider-aws-go version to v11 and terraform-cdk-go/cdktf version to v0.14.0, build is going smooth.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).